# Pandas str.contains returns false positives and ignores some values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to check for a set of substrings in each cell of a column and then put '`Yes`' if it contains any of those substrings.

I'm doing this:

`x.astype(str).loc[x['Body'].str.contains('$'), 'Sale'] = 'Yes'`

But a lot of the times it skips strings that have the '$' symbol and puts yes in others that don't have it.
I also tried checking cell by cell like this and it doesnt work either:

```
    if(x.iloc[i,1] != ''):
        if 'offer' in x.iloc[i,1]:
            x.at[i,'Sale'] = 'Yes'
        elif 'promo' in x.iloc[i,1]:
            x.at[i,'Sale'] = 'Yes'
        elif 'sale' in x.iloc[i,1]:
            x.at[i,'Sale'] = 'Yes'
```

Comment: [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) sets `regex=True` by default, and `$` is a special regex character. Either escape it like `str.contains('\$')`, or disable regex like `str.contains('$', regex=False)`

Comment: I tried both ways, the weird thing is that now It doesn't even write to the dataframe.